# Cargo build script to detect target min and max macOS version?

Tags: rust, build, rust-cargo, conditional-compilation, build-script

I'm writing a Rust wrapper for a C library that conditionally requires the `UniformTypeIdentifiers` framework depending on the values of `__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_ALLOWED` and `__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` (which are the minimum and maximum macOS versions targeted).  The C library does conditional compilation that uses the `UniformTypeIdentifiers` library (which was introduced recently) because the old way of doing things is now deprecated.

Is there a way to obtain these two values (the minimum and maximum macOS versions targeted) in `build.rs` so that I can decide whether to emit the `cargo:rustc-link-lib=framework=UniformTypeIdentifiers` line that links the library?  I can't simply emit it all the time, because on older Macs this will lead to a build error, since the library would be unavailable.

Comment: Clarification, does your thing compile without `UniformTypeIdentifiers` framework on older systems?

Comment: @AhmedMasud Yes. It only needs UniformTypeIdentifiers on newer systems, or if I pass a compilation flag to force it to do things in a particular way. However, whatever I do, I still need to figure out what version the build is targeting, so that I can add the correct libraries, or perhaps tell the C library to compile with certain flags.

Comment: I don't think you can obtain those values, because I don't think they're _defined_. Contrary to a CPU version, rustc does not know (to my knowledge) what OS version we compile into; there is only the minimum supported version. So your best bet is to introduce a feature.

Comment: Isn't the minimum supported version precisely what I want then?